# What is the best practice to define the routing logic in branch deep links?

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, deep-linking, branch.io

I was going through the reference documentation of [Branch on Cocoapods](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Branch/0.11.3/#class-reference) under the callback it suggests that the routing logic be kept. Heres is what logic I need to implement, but I could not figure out anything apart from an if-else logic. I want to induce a key--> functionality logic instead, what is the way it should be done?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];
    [branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions isReferrable:YES andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary *params, NSError *error) {
        // route the user based on what's in params
        // currently implemented as if-else logic
       if ([params objectForKey:@"key1"]){
           /*Do something*/
       }
       else if ([params objectForKey:@"key2"]){
          /*Do something else*/
       }
    }];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this, would be by passing a url with many components rather than individual keys. 
For example the metadata you pass could be :

```
abc.com/val1/val2
```

rather than having separate values as `key1,key2...`

This way,you can parse the url to get the separate path components and branch your routing accordingly.

This will also let you have multiple routes and values, without adding a new key-value pair in the dashboard each time.

Hope this answers your question.